# Can we override the default validation built into html5 input type url or email

Tags: html, validation

In html5 with input type url, what are the default rules for a valid url and if we also  specify a custom pattern attribute along side the type will it override the default rules of validation? e.g. in the following line, will pattern attribute ovrerride the default rules?

`<input type="url" name="website" pattern="https?://.+" title="Include http://">`

Comment: Your answer's at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Answer (score 2):

Per [the requirements in the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-input-pattern), yes, the `pattern` value does supersede the default validation requirements for the input type of the element:

> If an `input` element has a `pattern` attribute specified, and the attribute's value, when compiled as a JavaScript regular expression with only the "u" flag specified, compiles successfully, then the resulting regular expression is the element's **compiled pattern regular expression**.
>
> **Constraint validation**: If the element's value is not the empty string, and either the element's `multiple` attribute is not specified or it does not apply to the input element given its `type` attribute's current state, and the element has a *compiled pattern regular expression* but that regular expression does not match the entirety of the element's value, then the element is suffering from a pattern mismatch.

Try your snippet in a browser: If for example you enter `ftp://foo` into that control, browsers will give you a message saying something like, “Match the requested format: **Include http://**”.